# Select option car Mercedes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I am on http://www.mister-auto.com/

I want select an option of the dropbox car brand, option 6 - Mercedes car in the car brand in the dropbox car selector section, i tried out this script, but it doesn' t seems to do anything

```
selenium.open("http://www.mister-auto.com/")
selenium.click("//*[@id=\"f_select_marque\"]/optgroup[1]/option[6]")
```

Any idea why nothing happens ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is in **JAVA**

You can select the required option from a drop down using **Select** class of **Selenium**

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.mister-auto.com/");
    Select option = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("f_select_marque")));
    option.selectByVisibleText("Mercedes-Benz");
    // OR
    // option.selectByValue("74");  

    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//option[text()='Model']")));
        Select option1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("f_select_modele")));
        option1.selectByValue("530");
    }
```

Comment: Hi cruisepandey, i would like to get also the car model, so base on your code, i write:         Select carmodel = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_modele")));
        carmodel.selectByValue("530"); but doesn' t do anything, can you help me out, thanks

Comment: @dtjmsy : Can you  provide the manual steps to select car model ? Wesbsite is not in english. I'm having hard time to read anything on the site :(

Comment: hi, manual steps are very basic: select a brand ( mercedes) than a model than the motor type, here is the english version of the website http://www.mister-auto.co.uk/en/

Comment: @dtjmsy : you can refer the updated answer . and update the result here !

Comment: does it works on your side ? mine i have the error waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //option[text()='Model'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) on the french website

Comment: Yes it's working. I'll share the whole code in few minutes.

Comment: @dtjmsy : it will give error on french site because this is //option[text()='Model']  not available in french site.

Comment: I changed the XPath to //option[text()='Choisissez un modèle'], it works fine now, cheers all, and particularly @cruisepandy :)

Comment: Glad that It worked for you ! you can use this cssSelector, if you want "select[id='f_select_modele']>option"  , the benefit is you won't have to change the locator in case language changes. Rest I have posted at this SO Post :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331707/select-a-car-brand-model-motor-on-chaining-dropdown-list/50332307#50332307

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium with Java go for Select

```
 //need to pass dropdown location
 Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("f_select_marque")));
 //option text which need to select
    s.selectByVisibleText("Volkswagen");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium with C#, You can select required option from drop down as follows.

```
ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.mister-auto.com/");
var car = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("f_select_marque"));
var selectElem = new SelectElement(car);
selectElem.SelectByText("Mercedes-Benz");
```

Comment: Hi, I have the message he namespace SelectElement could not be found, i' am having those imports: using NUnit.Framework;

using NUnit;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

Comment: @dtjmsy : Import "using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;" and try again

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest below

```
   ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
   webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.mister-auto.com/");
   var car =webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option.hlight:nthchild(7)"));
   car.Click();
```