# Select a car brand > model > motor on chaining dropdown list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am on http://www.mister-auto.com/

I would like to chain the dropdown lists, by choosing the car brand, model and motor type

so i tried out the following code:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\geckodriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.get("http://www.mister-auto.com/");

    // Select the car brand
    Select option = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_marque")));
    option.selectByVisibleText("Mercedes-Benz");

    // Select the car model
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("f_select_modele")));

    Select carmodel = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_modele")));
    carmodel.selectByValue("530");

    // Select the car motor
    Select carmotor = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_type")));
    carmotor.selectByValue("7523");
```

The car brand selection is ok, but the model and the motor type, nothing happens

Can you help me out

thanks

Yves

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\geckodriver\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
webDriver.get("http://www.mister-auto.com/");  

// Select the car brand
Select option = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_marque")));
option.selectByVisibleText("Mercedes-Benz");  

// Select the car model  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[id='f_select_modele']>option")));
Select carmodel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("f_select_modele")));
carmodel .selectByValue("530"); 

// Select the car motor 

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[id='f_select_type']>option")));
Select carmotor = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_type")));
carmotor.selectByValue("7523");
```

Comment: @dtjmsy : This code is working fine with both the versions English and French and on my side , Please check this on your side.

Answer (score 0):

As per the website you have provided as `http://www.mister-auto.com/` to chain the *Dropdown Lists* by choosing the *Car Brand*, *Model* and *Motor Type* you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the desired elements to be clickable and you can use the following solution :

Code Block :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class dropDown_mister_auto_com {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriver.get("http://www.mister-auto.com/");

        // Select the car brand
        new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("f_select_marque")));
        Select option = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_marque")));
        option.selectByVisibleText("Mercedes-Benz");

        // Select the car model
        new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("f_select_modele")));
        Select carmodel = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_modele")));
        carmodel.selectByValue("530");

        // Select the car motor
        new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("f_select_type")));
        Select carmotor = new Select(webDriver.findElement(By.id("f_select_type")));
        carmotor.selectByValue("7523");
    }
}
```

Browser Snapshot :

[image: mister-auto]

Comment: This answer did not deserve a downvote without explanation.  I upvoted it.